# Regular expression to find a lowercase letter followed by an uppercase

Tags: regex, grep, textwrangler

I have difficulty using Regular Expression (Grep) in TextWrangler to find occurrences of lowercase letter followed by uppercase. For example:

This announcement **meansStudents** are welcome.

In fact, I want to split the occurrence by adding a colon so that it becomes **means: Students**

I have tried:

```
[a-z][A-Z]
```

But this expression does not work in TextWrangler.

****EDIT***: here are the exact contexts in which the occurrences appear (I mean only with these font colors).*

```
<font color =#48B700>  - Stột jlăm wẻ baOne hundred and three<br></font>

<font color =#C0C0C0>     »» Qzống pguộc lyời ba yghìm fảy dyổiTo live a life full of vicissitudes, to live a life marked by ups and downs<br></font>

"baOne" and "dyổiTo" must be "ba: One" and "dyổi: To"
```

Could anyone help? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do believe (don't have TextWrangler at hand though) that you need to search for `([a-z])([A-Z])` and replace it with: `\1: \2`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope! It just finds any adjacent letters.

Comment: Any adjacent letters, even two lowercase ones? Then maybe you need to tick 'Case sensitive' box then?

Comment: That's exactly the problem. Thank you so much! But it now turns to another problem: it finds and replaces all the values, even the unwanted one FileMaker into File: Maker.

Comment: Unfortunately, you haven't described the nature of your text. Of course, the expression I suggested looks for any lowercase letter following any uppercase one, regardless of any context. Maybe if you give us an example of your text we will be able to provide a better solution.

Comment: Still not clear what must be separated by the colon, and what should be left unchanged.

Comment: Well Igor, between each of these two font-color tags, there is one occurrence of lowercase letter followed by uppercase that need separating by the colon. All other occurrences outside these two font-color tags are left unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `([a-z])([A-Z])` with `\1:\2` - I don't have TextWrangler, but it works on Notepad++

The parenthesis are for capturing the data, which is referred to using `\1` syntax in the replacement string

Comment: Thanks, Amarghosh. But it still does not work. Anyway, my document contains HTML tags and the expression seems to include everything between the font tags.

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck in TextWrangler. I don't have Notepad++ for Mac :( to try.

Answer (score 2):

This question is ages old, but I stumbled upon it, so someone else might, as well. The [OP's comment to Igor's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756382/regular-expression-to-find-a-lowercase-letter-followed-by-an-uppercase#comment10913114_8756510) clarified how the task was meant to be described (& could have be added to the description).

To match only those font-specific lines of the HTML replace

`(?<=<font color =#(?:48B700|C0C0C0)>)(.*?[a-z])([A-Z])`

with `\1: \2`

Explanation:

- `(?<=[fixed-length regex])` is a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and means *"if my match has this just before it"*
- `(?:48B700|C0C0C0)` is an unnamed group to match only 2 colours. Since they are of the same length, they work in a lookbehind (that needs to be of fixed length)
- `(.*?[a-z])([A-Z])` will match everything after the `>` of those begin font tags up to your Capital letters.
- The `\1: \2` replacement is the same as in Igor's response, only that `\1` will match the entire first string that needs separating.

Addition:

Your input strings contain special characters and the part you want to split may very well end in one. In this case they won't be caught by `[a-z]` alone. You will need to add a character ranger that captures [all the letters you care about](https://unicode-table.com/en/), something like

`(?<=<font color =#(?:48B700|C0C0C0)>)(.*?[a-zḁ-ῼ])([A-Z])`

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct pattern for identifying lower case and upper case letters, however, you will need to check matching to be Case Sensitive within the Find/Replace dialogue.